Visual Studio Extension Not Working for Network Service Account
I have an azure pipeline using Network Service account to run. All the while, there is no issue until last month it started fail to build.
After troubleshooting, I found out that when building vdproj file, it hit the error below:

E:\BuildAgent5_work\1\s\src\XXX_Setup\XXX_Setup.vdproj : error : The
operation was canceled. [E:\BuildAgent5_work\1\s\build\Build.proj]
One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.

I tried to use PsTools to login as Network Service account and open devenv for the vdproj file, it hit the error below:

Unable to open project: xxxx.vdproj

I have checked the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project 2022 extension already installed and enabled. I have also granted the Network Service account to the extension folder but the issue still persists.
Is there anything else I can check?

According to your description, it has been working fine until last month when it started failing to build. Have you made any changes during this period? For example, the agent version or the account used, and the related software versions, etc. You can also compare the successful log and the failed log to check if there is any difference.

This question is similar to: Azure pipeline: One or more project in the solution were not loaded properly. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
